# Redirected to 404 after completing Team Survey

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, survey

I took a survey regarding Stack Overflow for Teams. After completion of survey, it took me to 404 page.

[image]

Is there any reason for this error? Where was this link supposed to lead to?

Comment: Same for me.  I was looking forward to a "We'll send you some swag for completing this survey" page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's my bad, sorry about that. I forgot about a site setting that controls whether that route (in addition to the others used by the survey) is enabled.

Flipped the setting on now, so the completion links should no longer 404. Thank you for the report!

Comment: Too bad. I couldn't see where it'd lead to. :P

Comment: @AJ It's not that exciting, honestly - it just records the completion and redirects to the homepage with a confirmation toast. If you refresh the same URL (if you still have it), you'll see it. :)

Comment: Yes, I did see that.